# I want use plural translation with variable on Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, translation, laravel-5.3

In Laravel 5.3, I want use translation:

```
'items' => ':number item|:number items'
```

And use **trans()**:

```
trans('folder/file.items', ['number' => 0])
```

Give 0 item, 1 item, and 2 items.

Answer (score 5):

Read following documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/localization#pluralization

In Laravel 5.3:

```
'items' => '[0,1] :count item |[2,Inf] :count items',
```

In Laravel 5.4 (https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/localization#pluralization):

```
'items' => '[0,1] :count item |[2,*] :count items',
```

And in **view**:

```
{{ trans_choice('app.items', 5) }}
```

Count placeholder will automaticaly set number 5

Comment: Laravel does not allow me to do what I want to do. Using their metod, I get the sentence without the number...

Answer (score 2):

Just use the str_plural() helper function provided by Laravel!

```
{{ $items }} {{ str_plural('item', $items) }}
```

The variable $item must be a number, not an array or collection. In case $items is a collection, you have to use count($items) to get the number of items in the collection. It will then look like this:

```
{{ $items }} {{ str_plural('item', count($items)) }}
```

**Reference** (Larvel 5.3): https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-str-plural